# How to animate the modal from bottom to top with the scaled back-window in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to open a modal from the bottom to top with the back-window(main view) to be **scaled down** like this:
[image]

That would be helpful to know the package or library can do the animation like the image above. I appreciate for that!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using "Animated" component provide by react-native itself.

Here Animated docs [click here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated)

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: do you have any example for me to refer, because i'm not strong at animation stuff?

Comment: oky, can you explain exactly what type of animation you want that way i bulit  a dummy code for you.

Comment: i need a scaled-down animation for the main view as long as it presents like the above image. thanks for your help!